# How can I add a question in plain text?

Tags: support, questions, markdown

I tried with HTML or Code. I get strange answers. Too many links, but I only want to show some code. And it removes text from my question.

Why is there not a plain text function?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. If you want "plain text", just type in your question. What's the problem?

Comment: Maybe try what you want in the [sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)?

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to post html and do some of your tags end up missing? Perhaps put the raw text you're trying to post online somewhere so we can have a look at it.

Comment: Try indenting it by 4 spaces..? Hard to tell what you mean..

Comment: Isn't this question you've asked in plain text?

Comment: @Oded He is so much into programming until he switched definitions, so plain text is code and code is plain text ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: I don't understand, what are you actually trying to say boy?

Comment: @stackoverloop im sure its just a language barrier but F.Y.I refering to people as "boy" can be considered offensive

Answer (score 3):

There is functionality to highlight the code part and other part of the question.

Like your code is this

code

and you have leave it as it is.

you need to select your code and then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> to highlight the code like this:

```
code
```

I hope this is the solution of your problem.

> **NOTE:** SO provides the editor to add the question or answer in a good format. you can use
>   the toolbar also that appears in the above or textarea.

Comment: An alternative to `ctrl` + `k` is to use the `{ }` button

Comment: Richard Tingle's response refers to the button in the row of formatting buttons above the body of a question or answer.